# Slow Pandas script - efficiency gains or bad code?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of around 2 million rows. I am running the following code, but it is taking far too long to run. Have I written inefficient code?

```
ids = set(df['ids'])

for id_i in ids:

    if df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i]['playDirection'].iloc[0] == 'left':

        df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'x'] = 5 - df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'x']
        df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'y'] = 10 - df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'y']

    else:

        df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'x'] = df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'x'] - 5
        df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'y'] = df.loc[df['ids'] == id_i, 'y'] - 10

    df.loc[(df['ids'] == id_i) & (df['frame'] > 10), ['x', 'y']] = 0
```

EDIT 1:

Is this a potential solution?

**ANSWER: NOT REALLY**

```
def func1(group):

    if group['playDirection'].iloc[0] == 'left':

        group.loc[:, 'x'] = 5 - group.loc[:, 'x']
        group.loc[:, 'y'] = 10 - group.loc[:, 'y']

    else:
        group.loc[:, 'x'] = group.loc[:, 'x'] - 5
        group.loc[:, 'y'] = group.loc[:, 'y'] - 10

    group.loc[group['frame'] > 10, ['x', 'y']] = 0

df.groupby('ids').apply(func1)
```

EDIT 2:

Sample Data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1voud_qF8bGyKWT0j9JU_ftkIzAwnSilM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes you have. Updating cells iteratively is really slow. This can be done with `groupby`.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. In fact, you are not using the benefits of pandas at all. if you can add a sample data and what you're looking to do, we can help you better.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have amended my question with a solution I believe is in line with your comment. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Not really. Why don't you include sample data and expected output?

Comment: I have added a link to sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm shooting in the dark here since there's no data to play with. The first part of our code:

```
if group['playDirection'].iloc[0] == 'left':

    group.loc[:, 'x'] = 5 - group.loc[:, 'x']
    group.loc[:, 'y'] = 10 - group.loc[:, 'y']

else:
    group.loc[:, 'x'] = group.loc[:, 'x'] - 5
    group.loc[:, 'y'] = group.loc[:, 'y'] - 10
```

tries to look at the first row of each `group`. So you can do in the vectorized manner:

```
mask = df.groupby('ids')['playDirection'].transform('first') == 'left'

df['x'] = np.where(mask, 5 - df['x'], df['x'] - 5)
df['y'] = np.where(mask, 10 - df['y'], df['y'] - 10)
```

The last part:

```
group.loc[group['frame'] > 10, ['x', 'y']] = 0
```

doesn't seem to have anything to do with groupby, so it can be done on dataframe level:

```
df.loc[df['frame']>10, ['x','y']] = 0
```

---

TLDR: Try instead:

```
# first part
mask = df.groupby('ids')['playDirection'].transform('first') == 'left'

df['x'] = np.where(mask, 5 - df['x'], df['x'] - 5)
df['y'] = np.where(mask, 10 - df['y'], df['y'] - 10)

# second part
df.loc[df['frame']>10, ['x','y']] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, try if this works for you

```py
conditions = [df.playDirection == 'left', df.playDirection != 'left']
df.x = np.select(conditions, [5 - df.x, df.x - 5])
df.y = np.select(conditions, [10 - df.y, df.y - 10])

df.loc[df['frame'] > 10, ['x', 'y']] = 0
```

I'm basically selecting right value for x and y based your conditions.